# Term for Performing Action Early to Account for Delay of Transmission?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests, verbs, phrasal-verbs

In sports, such as football, a player will throw the ball to a spot early, so the ball arrives as the receiver arrives.

This concept is relevant outside of sports. For example, I could send a letter to one city while you're still in another city, but you'll receive it just as you arrive. I can add more technical examples if necessary.

Is there a term for this action? I've used "quarter-backing" in the past, but I've found myself in a situation where I need to describe this concept in a professional environment.

#### Example Sentence

I don't know if this is a single-word-request or phrase-request, but here's an example sentence:

> I sent the email on Friday, so I could ____ it as you arrived on Monday.

It may or may not fit with this sentence syntax.

> I quarter-backed the email on Friday, so you would receive it as you arrived on Monday.

Obviously this term sounds silly.

Comment: [_Deflection_, or "leading a target"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflection_(ballistics)) works perfectly in your first (football) example, but I do not see how it would work with the sample (email) sentence.

Comment: "Catch up with you"? I can't think of a single word expression...

Comment: BTW, to "quarter-back" something has an entirely different and more common usage, meaning to "call the play" or control the action.

Comment: So it would coincide with your arrival.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept is **anticipation**, in your context you'd either say **anticipating** or possibly **to anticipate** their arrival.

Answer (score 3):

**[Proactively](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/proactively)** might be the word you are looking for. It means

> serving to prepare for, intervene in, or control an expected occurrence or situation

Example: 
I proactively sent the email on Friday, so you would receive it as you arrived on Monday.

Anticipatory can also be used.

Comment: Proactively fits well. I also like anticipatory. I'm going to select the other answer, since it was posted first, but I upvoted your response.

Comment: I'm also going to upvote it - both *proactively* and (maybe) *pre-emptively* would also be useful in OP's situation of grammatical need :o)

Answer (score 1):

[Leading a target](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflection_(ballistics)) is the term used in shooting or sports, but would not apply to your mail example.

"Sending a message **beforehand** to your anticipated destination" seems to work.

Comment: Hi @MattGoodrich, I didn't read that comment. I googled "leading with a firearm" since that definition of lead wasn't in the dictionary I was using. The wiki page is what came up. Beforehand isn't adding value?

Comment: I didn't notice "beforehand" as your term and thought you were using the existing "leading a target" and "anticipated" responses. I apologize for my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***expedite***.

> I sent the email on Friday, so I could ***expedite*** it's arrival to
>   match your arrival on Monday.

businessdictionary.com:

> **[expedite](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/expedite.html)**
>
> To quicken the process; make faster.   "He asked the mail service for
>   an expedited delivery service, as the package needed to arrive
>   tomorrow."

Answer (score 0):

A verb which works well for both the sports and messaging examples is ***time***.

> I sent the email on Friday, so I could ***time*** it for your arrival
>   on Monday.

ODO:

> **[time](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/time)**  *VERB*
>
> **1** [with object and adverbial or infinitive] Plan, schedule, or arrange when (something) should happen or be done.
>
> ‘It's just a matter of timing your visit to coincide with when the
>   lily is in flower.’
>
> **1.1** Perform (an action) at a particular moment.
>
> ‘Russell's perfectly timed lob into the path of John Joe Maguire saw
>   the Town striker break the offside trap and pull clear of the
>   defence.’